# How to obtain standard errors of regression coefficients when using `netlm()` in `sna` package?

Tags: r, regression, sna

I run a network regression with `netlm()` in `sna` package. All results looks fine. However, I can't find a standard error for each of the coefficients. There are no standard errors in returned model object; `summary()` also does not export them. Is there any way to get them?

```
IV0 <- list(SEX, GRADE, YEAR)
M0 <- netlm(K1M, IV0, nullhyp = "qapspp", reps = 2000)

summary.default(M0)  ## check structure of returned model object

# Length Class  Mode     
# coefficients     4   -none- numeric  
# fitted.values  812   -none- numeric  
# residuals      812   -none- numeric  
# qr               4   qr     list     
# rank             1   -none- numeric  
# n                1   -none- numeric  
# df.residual      1   -none- numeric  
# tstat            4   -none- numeric  
# dist          8000   -none- numeric  
# pleeq            4   -none- numeric  
# pgreq            4   -none- numeric  
# pgreqabs         4   -none- numeric  
# nullhyp          1   -none- character
# names            4   -none- character
# intercept        1   -none- logical  

M0    ## print model object

# OLS Network Model

# Residuals:
#         0%        25%        50%        75%       100% 
# -0.3669251 -0.3376203 -0.3066127  0.6623797  0.7340360 

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate     Pr(<=b) Pr(>=b) Pr(>=|b|)
# (intercept)  0.271072656 0.966   0.034   0.0605   
# x1           0.009641084 0.602   0.398   0.8360   
# x2          -0.031007609 0.169   0.831   0.3440   
# x3           0.029304737 0.774   0.226   0.4660   

# Residual standard error: 0.47 on 808 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared: 0.002094  Adjusted R-squared: -0.001611 
# F-statistic: 0.5651 on 3 and 808 degrees of freedom, p-value: 0.6382 

summary(M0)    ## print model summary

# Test Diagnostics:

#   Null Hypothesis: qapspp 
#   Replications: 2000 
#   Coefficient Distribution Summary:

#       (intercept)       x1       x2       x3
#Min       -3.15189 -4.84538 -3.08131 -2.75036
#1stQ      -0.65506 -0.99759 -0.65075 -0.68183
#Median     0.01805 -0.09364  0.06947 -0.01831
#Mean       0.02510 -0.03473  0.03247 -0.01179
#3rdQ       0.69636  0.90936  0.72701  0.63639
#Max        3.29170  5.71549  2.71428  2.90498
```

Answer (score 3):

`sna::netlm()` does compute those standard errors in order to yield t-score as returned in `$tstat`, but it does not explicitly return those values. However, it can't be more straightforward to obtain them.

Recall that:

```
t-score = coefficient / standard.error
```

Since coefficients and t-score are reported, you can invert this formula to get standard.error:

```
standard.error = coefficient / t-score
```

So given your model `M0`, standard errors for coefficients are just:

```
with(M0, coefficients / tstat)
```

---

---

My initial answer is to compute those standard errors from the `$qr` object:

```
std_coef <- function (model) {
  sigma2 <- sum(model$residuals ^ 2) / model$df.residual
  Rinv <- backsolve(model$qr$qr, diag(model$rank))
  sqrt(rowSums(Rinv ^ 2) * sigma2)
  }

std_coef(M0)
```

This function is designed for `lmObject` returned by `lm()`. But since `netlm()` is based on `lm()` and also returns the `$qr` object, we can use it for `netlm()`, too.

However, as soon as I realize that `netlm()` returns t-score, I update my answer using that shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

Building on the previous answer, it is important to keep in mind that QAP doesn't use standard errors to evaluate significance - at least not directly. The procedure first computes coefficients and standard errors via OLS and then creates a distribution of test statistics via the specified permutation procedure (in this case, "qapspp"). The initial OLS coefficient is then compared to that distribution to evaluate significance. Assuming you want the standard errors from the OLS regression, you can simply vectorize the independent and dependent matrices and use good, old-fashioned `lm()`.

Using some toy networks, you can see how this works.

```
nets<-rgraph(25,3)
response<- nets[1,,]*2+nets[2,,]*5
fit <- netlm(response, nets, nullhyp="qapspp")
fit$coefficients

[1] -0.019743805  2.052129105  5.086171312 -0.003684872

#View the distribution of the third independent matrix
plot(density(fit$dist[,4]))
abline(v=fit$tstat[4])
```

[image]

Now, you can look at the OLS coefficients and standard errors using `lm()` and `gvectorize()`

```
ols <- lm(gvectorize(response) ~ gvectorize(nets[1,,]) + 
          gvectorize(nets[2,,]) + gvectorize(nets[3,,]))
```

Compare the coefficients from the two models to see that they are the same:

```
fit$coefficients
[1] -0.019743805  2.052129105  5.086171312 -0.003684872

as.numeric(ols$coefficients)
[1] -0.019743805  2.052129105  5.086171312 -0.003684872
```

Using `summary(ols)` yields your standard errors.

However, these standard errors are unreliable given the nature of network data, something covered in detail in Krackhardt (1988) and elsewhere. They are NOT used to compute the p-values in the summary output for `netlm()`. The generated distribution is used instead. Standard errors are used in that process to generate the t-statistics, but significance depends on where the observed t-stat falls in the generate distribution, as shown above.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. Small question: Do you know if it is customary to report standard errors when reporting QAP output? From your answer I assume not, but wanted to make sure. Thank you.